# Is any theorem prover able to prove quadratization relations without knowing the proof strategy that humans used?

Tags: software-request, automated-theorem-proving, provers, optimization, combinatorics

### Motivation

In discrete optimization, our goal is often to optimize a function of binary variables, such as:

$$\tag{1} {\scriptsize 
5 - 3b_1 - b_2 - b_3 + 2b_1b_3 - 3b_2b_3 + 2b_1b_2b_3 - 3b_4 + b_1b_2 + 2b_2b_4 + 2b_2b_3b_4, ~b_i \in \{0,1\}}.
$$

In Eqs 12-14 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.6758), I showed that finding the $(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)$ combination that minimizes that function, is all we need to do to factor the number 143 (from which that function was derived step-by-step in Eqs. 1-11). But that function is ***cubic*** due to the $2b_1b_2b_3$ term, and it would need to be ***quadratic*** in order to use fast optimizers such as Kolmogorov's [QPBO software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_pseudo-Boolean_optimization) on classical computers, or on [D-Wave's quantum annealing hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum_processors) in which 4 qubits (e.g. electrons that can be in a spin-up $\uparrow$; or 0-state, or a spin-down $\downarrow$ or 1-state) would simply be coupled to each other with strengths proportional to the coefficients in the function, and the ground-state/lowest-energy configuration (e.g. $\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow$) tells us the minimum of the function.

### Quadratization

The above function can be transformed into a quadratic one that still has the same minimum, occurring at the same place, by ***quadratizing*** the higher-degree terms. For example, Eq. 76 of my [book on quadratization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.04405v2) tells us that by introducing an auxiliary variable $b_a$ we have:

$$
b_1b_2b_3 = \min_{b_a}\left( b_a - b_2b_a - b_3b_a +b_1b_a +b_2b_3\right), \tag{2}
$$

so we can replace $b_1b_2b_3$ by the quadratic right-hand side and minimizing over all variables including the auxiliary variable will be equivalent to minimizing the original function. This quadratization can be verified with just a few lines of MATLAB/Octave code:

```
b=dec2bin(2^4-1:-1:0)-'0';
b1=b(:,1);b2=b(:,2);b3=b(:,3);ba=b(:,4);
LHS = min(reshape(b1.*b2.*b3,2,[]));
RHS = min(reshape(ba - b2.*ba - b3.*ba + b1.*ba +b2.*b3,2,[]));
isequal(LHS,RHS) % answer is 1
```

### The need for theorem provers

My book contains over 100 such quadratizations, and it comes with [this MATLAB code](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Book_About_Quadratization/blob/master/everything_else/reproducing.m) which manually tries to verify each quadratization like I just did for the above one, ***however*** some of them quadratizations apply to $b_1b_2\cdots b_k$ for an arbitrary integer $k$, for example:
$$
b_{1}b_{2}\ldots b_{k} = \min_{b_{a_i}} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{k-2}b_{a_{i}}(k-i-1+b_{i}-\sum_{j=i+1}^{k}b_{j})\right)+b_{k-1}b_{k}. \tag{3}
$$

In that final equation, we can certainly verify that it's true with a similar MATLAB code ***by fixing the value of $k$***, and we can do this for various $k$ values, but this technique cannot be powerful enough to prove that the equation is true ***for any integer $k$.***

**Is any ATP (automatic theorem prover) likely to be able to prove Eq. 3 of this question, without me telling it how humans proved it?**

Comment: I actually debated with myself whether I should restrict it to ATPs and I think you're right. I should broaden it (after teaching my classes today).